# How do you run nodeos as a non-root user?

Tags: nodeos, block-producer, security

I'm working on one node which is running on a testnet, and since I'm kinda new to this environment I'm wondering how can I drop privilege level to a non-root user for running a node on a server?

Can I go with:

```
sudo adduser nodeos --shell=/bin/false
```

then:

```
chown -R nodeos:nodeos Node
```

and then run as a user?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. nodeos itself does not require any special permissions that comes with root unless you want it to listen on a privileged port.